# Choosing the proper order type to preserve profits on crypto exchanges

Tags: trading, limit-order, order-execution

I bought ETH at approx. 1700. It went to 1800. I wanted to preserve my gains and created a `LIMIT` order. My thoughts that if the price "came back the other way", then it would hit the `LIMIT` level I placed and sell at $1800.

Instead, the software sold my ETH immediately (acting more like a `MARKET` order). I did not want this.

What order should I have chosen? Should it have been something like a `STOP LIMIT` or `STOP MARKET`? Is there some kind of guide out there that can advise the type of order to place given a certain situation?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you send a limit order to sell at 1800 and the market price has liquid buyers, at say 1900, most exchanges will match the order to the 1900 buyer and get you the improved price.

The order type you are looking for if I understand your desire correctly is a *sell stop*, that will only execute once a price falls to a certain amount. Good intro to order types/further reading [here](https://www.investopedia.com/investing/basics-trading-stock-know-your-orders/).